# Can Kannel use number extensions?

Tags: sms, gsm, modem, sms-gateway, kannel

I may set up an SMS gateway using Kannel and a Huawei E220 GSM modem.

Now, my question is, is it possible for Kannel to detect extensions appended to the server's phone number in incoming messages (e.g. someone texts 12345#28 instead of 12345) and/or to send outgoing messages with such extensions appended?

Answer (score 1):

Kannel supports deliver to recipient addresses with a '#' in them, but not by default.

By default Kannel's smsbox (HTTP I/F) has "0123456789 +-" as valid recipient characters. These can be extended to support '#' but setting

`group = smsbox
...
sendsms-chars="0123456789 +-#"`

That's all well and good but the key is does the underlying messaging layer you use for delivery support it also. For example when testing with a modem (kannel 'at' driver) - the modem returned an ERROR on the send command so it may also perform some addressing validation. Also when testing with kannel 'SMPP' connection to a provider the submit_sm request also returned an error. So Yes Kannel supports delivery to/from  recipient/destination addresses formatted in that way - but that may be a moot point.

HTHs

Cheers,
Alan